# One million rows update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have two tables.

Table A: columns A, B, C are products

```
ID  SDate           A       B       C       PercentageVal
---------------------------------------------------------
1   02/22/2021      3.04    0.43    7.15        ??
2   04/13/2021      12.12   5.32    0.22        ??
3   06/07/2021      1.01    1.11    8.02        ??
4   03/01/2021      2.09    4.09    9.02        ??
```

Table B:

```
ID  TableAID    Product     StartDate       EndDate     PValue
---------------------------------------------------------
1       1       A           01/01/2021      06/30/2021  10
2       2       B           03/01/2021      05/31/2021  12
3       3       C           02/01/2021      06/30/2021  10
```

To calculate the PercentageVal in Table A, the following logic is required.

**Step 1:** To get PercentValue for the Product columns A,B,and C in Table A

```
select B.Product, B.PValue  
into #temp 
from A 
join B on A.SDate between B.StartDate and B.EndDate;
```

**Step 2:** Here I'm generating dynamic query to calculate PercentageVal for Table A

```
Select 'Update A set PercentageVal= '+ string_agg(Product * (PValue/100)) + ' Where ID='+ B.TableAID 
From B;
```

Table A has approximately 1 million rows. With this executing a million of Update statements taking 20 mins of time.

Is there any better way to update table A?

**Expected Result**:

In TableA Row1, SDate is Feb so only products A and C are eligible for calculation. As Product B's Start and End dates in TableB are not matched.
So I need Sum of

```
(A*(10/100) + C*(10/100)) => (3.04*(10/100) + 7.15*(10/100)) => 1.019
```

Similarly for Row2 all three products can be taken for calculation, as the SDate satisfies the condition.

```
(A*(10/100) + B*(12/100) + C*(10/100)) => (12.12*0.10)+(5.32*0.12)+(0.22*0.10) => 1.872
```

Please note that products taken for calculation is dynamic, based on SDate should fall between StartDate and EndDate in TableB.

Comment: Edit your question and show the result you are using.

Comment: Expected results would help immensely

Comment: Edited the question with Expected Result

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `apply`:

```
update a
    set percentageval = b.cal
    from a outer apply
         (select sum(v.val * b.pvalue / 100) as calc
          from b cross apply
               (values ('A', a.a), ('B', a.b), ('C', a.c)
               ) v(product, val) 
          where a.sdate between b.startdate and b.enddate and
                a.id = b.tableaid and
                v.product = b.product
         ) b;
```